# Correcting randomisation function for chance of returning original value

Tags: probability

I am implementing some GDPR-related data randomisation code; the general rules I need to abide to are as follow:

For each user that requested to be GDPR deleted, there is a certain set of data fields that will need to be passed through a two-step randomisation function.

*As an example let's say that we only care about one field, `favourite colour`, for which there are 6 possible values the user could have picked from (1:'red', 2:'blue', 3:'yellow', 4:'green', 5:'orange', 6:'purple').*

For each field, we "roll the dice" separately. The first roll is to determine whether the field should be randomised or not based on some percentage.
Let's say, 15% (so, about 1/7 deleted user will actually get the field randomised).
If the above roll returns `TRUE` then we perform a second "dice roll", this time to assign a value at random among those that are "legal" for said field.

*For our hypothetical user, the first dice roll returned `TRUE` and thus we will run the second function tasked with picking one of the six possible values listed above and replacing it from the original.*

Returning the same value as the original is permitted.

Which means that even over a large sample of users, we will never achieve a situation by which "15% of users have their favourite colour field altered", because there is a chance that the random function will return the same value.

And we finally get to my actual question: if I wanted to account for that, and increase the initial probability so that the actual "on the ground" probability is 15%, how would I go about that?

I would assume it is

target_probability + target_probability * chance_of_value_within_set

so

0.15 + 0.15 * 0.1666... (1/6)

but lacking proper maths training I am not sure this is the right approach.

Comment: There's also the option of "roll a new value, and keep re-rolling until you get something different from the old value". Then, you can just decide to do this with $15\%$ probability. On average, this shouldn't take many rerolls.

Comment: For reasons that I won't bore you with, we decided to implement this process in SQL, so looping constructs aren't really on the table. 
I was also thinking of creating an extra field of type array for each user and popping out the value they originally have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's almost, but not quite, correct. Let $I$ denote the initial probability, $T$ the target probability, and $C$ the chance of choosing the original value when trying to randomize (so that $1-C$ is the chance of altering the original value). The relationship between these quantities is
$$
T = I(1-C),
$$
since the proportion $I$ of all entries get an attempted randomization, and within those the proportion $1-C$ actually get randomized (on average). So if you know the target probability $T$ and the chance $C$ of choosing the original value, the best choice for the initial probability is
$$
I = \frac T{1-C},
$$
which is a bit larger than the $I+IC$ you proposed. In the given example, we would set the initial probability to be $\dfrac{0.15}{1-0.1666\cdots} = 0.18$.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost correct.

Let $t$ be the target probability of getting a different value.

Suppose we are trying to achieve this probability by deciding to reroll with probability $r$, and choosing one of $n$ values when we reroll. Then the probability of getting a different value is $r \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$: we must reroll, and give that we reroll, we must get one of the $n-1$ new values.

Solving, $t = r \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$ gives $r = t \cdot \frac{n}{n-1}$, which we can split up into $r = t + \frac{t}{n-1}$. (Your formula is $t + \frac tn$, which is almost but not quite right.)

For example, in this case, there are $n=6$ possible colors, and we are aiming for a target probability of $t = 0.15$. Then we should take $r = 0.15 \cdot \frac65 = 0.18$: reroll with an $18\%$ probability.

Comment: Thank you! I marked Greg's answer as correct simply due to timing, but yours is just as correct.